# Call to undefined method App\User::events()

Tags: laravel

I am trying to store data into the database, but the error I'm getting is:

> Call to undefined method App\User::events()

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'slug'  => 'required|unique:events',
            'body'  => 'required',
            'date'  => 'date_format:M-d-y H:i:s',
            'time'  => 'required'
        ]);

        $request->user()->events()->create($request->all());

        return redirect('/backend/blog')->with('message', 'Your event was created successfully');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'slug'  => 'required|unique:events',
        'body'  => 'required',
        'date'  => 'date_format:M-d-y H:i:s',
        'time'  => 'required'
    ]);

    $user = User::create($request->all()); // create the user
    event(new UserRegistered($user)); // Add your own event class name.

    return redirect('/backend/blog')->with('message', 'Your event was created successfully');
}
```

**Note:** Assuming that you have created the `UserRegistered` event. And call it by `event` helper method.

Comment: can u please tell me what to do if i want to add user_id as well in this code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you do not have any `events()` relationship in you `User` model.
Assuming you have `Event` model, you can write like in `User` model:

```
public function events()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
}
```